# Salesforce Lightning Flow Email Alert Using Classic Template

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert, deliverability, lightning-flow-builder

I am having somewhat of a dilemma after building a Flow to replace an out Workflow Rule that sent an email alert as a workflow action.  The new Flow has three actions; Get Record, Update Record, and Email Alert.  The email alert is setup to use the values from earlier in the flow to set the inputs for the "Alert Representative" email alert.  The "Alert Representative" email uses a classic template.  The flow works and the email alert gets sent out, however, the email being received shows "noreply@salesforce.com on behalf of..." without the current users name.  In the past, the workflow rule use to display the name of the current user, however, when converted to a flow it does not.

I have confirmed that the Org-Wide Address noreply is set as Default No-Reply Address as purpose.  I have also confirmed that all check boxes are checked under Deliverabilty > Bounce Management and Email Security Compliance.

Anyone else run into this issue?  If so, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.